# Use all .h files in a subproject of an Xcode project

Tags: xcode, file-management

I have a project that contains a git submodule from another project, and, after adding the project as a dependency, and building successfully, I cannot figure out how to get the .h files from it into my project.

The subproject is not a framework, its simply another xcode project with its own .app file.  The git submodule is in a folder contained in my projects top level folder so `~/Documents/MyProject/Mysubproject/`

Thank you.

Comment: You can just add the .h files to your project, selecting "Do not copy files". That will keep them in the original folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.  I had to turn the subproject into a Static Cocoa Touch Library.